# JQuery or Modernizr is not working in IE and other legacy browsers?

Tags: jquery, css, modernizr

I am trying to make a site with an off-canvas navigation that slides in on click of the ' navigation list ' icon in the upper-left.

I first developed it and powered it using CSS3 Transitions and :target and that works.

Then, with the help of StackOverflow, I developed a version powered by JQuery 1.9 with a similar effect. This version works fine.

Then, I combined them and am using Modernizr to detect when :target selector is not supported, it loads the JQuery from before.
I tried it in chrome and it works— meaning it works when CSS3 Transitions and :target is supported. 
But, then I tried it in IE 7 and it doesn't work.

I don't know if this is because Modernizr and the custom :target test is not working and loading the jQuery or if the JQuery is not working now for some reason.

Here it is: http://goo.gl/ztbwe

I would really appreciate all and any help in getting this to work in browsers that support CSS3 Transitions and :target and when either is not supported provide & execute the jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `odd()` function (Line 62 in menu.html) has an extra comma:

```
function odd() {
    $('.content').animate({
        marginLeft : '20%',
        marginRight : '-20%', // <-- bad comma
    });
}
```

Next time just open your demo in Internet Explorer (or whatever browser is giving you problems), and hit <kbd>F12</kbd> (dev tools). IE lets you switch the browser version you wish to view the page in, so if your in IE, then in dev tools set the 'browser mode' to IE7, then open the console, and inspect your errors.

Comment: Thank you. Oh, I didn't know IE had Dev tools. I only know of them in Chrome, FF, and Opera.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I fixed it. Then I tried in the older IE again and its still not working. According to the dev tools it has a problem with the '$' character in my JS.

To me that seems that would be an error if the jQuery lib is not loaded, but I see no reason why its not loading.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this new error and hopefully getting the js working in legacy browsers ?

Comment: You could try wrapping the code that needs to execute after jQuery has loaded in this: `$(function() {
      /* Paste your jQuery-requiring code in here. */
    });`

Comment: Okay, I added a document.ready() to the parts that are jQuery. Now, it works in IE 10 and IE 9, but not in less than IE 9. I am getting errors that I don't know how to interpret.

I think one of them is with line 48 and other is object expected. Don't know what the second one is at all, but when I make the $(document).ready() the first thing and encapsulate everything inside it, the first error goes away, but then i get another object expected error and then it also doesn't work in IE 10 and IE 9.

I would really appreciate it if you could help me figure this out so that it works in IE 6+.